# Nullspace of Matrix times projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, projection-matrices

I'm given a matrix X, a matrix A and a projection matrix $ P_{N(A)} $ .
What is the nullspace of $X \cdot P_{N(A)}$ ?
My script says its $ N(X) \cap N(A) $.
Is it true ? Why ?
Thanks

Comment: Does $R(A)$ stand for the *row space* of $A$ or for the *range* (column space) of $A$? Since $N(A)$ is the orthogonal complement of the row space, I'm inclined to believe they mean that.  ... At any rate, I believe their answer is incorrect.

Comment: I'm sorry, made a mistake writing the question. I'm looking for the Nullspace of $ X \cdot P_{N(A)} $

Comment: The orthogonal compliment of N(A) is $ R(A^T) $ right ? So the $ R(A^T) $ is part of the Subspace Im looking for. But why is N(X) also part of it? How do I know what happens with it when I multiply with $ P_{N(A)} $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, any vector in $N(A)^\perp = R(A^\top)$ is in the nullspace of this matrix, since it projects to $0\in N(A)$. Next, any vector in $N(A)\cap N(X)$ is in the nullspace: If $v\in N(A)\cap N(X)$, then $P_{N(A)}v = v$, and so $X\cdot P_{N(A)}v = Xv = 0$. Thus, any linear combination of such vectors is in the nullspace, so we claim the nullspace is precisely
$$N(A)\cap N(X) + R(A^\top).$$

We've argued that any vector in that subspace is in the nullspace. Why is that everything? Take any $v\in N(X\cdot P_{N(A)})$ and write $v=v_1+v_2$, where $v_1\in N(A)$ and $v_2\in N(A)^\perp = R(A^\top)$. Then
$$0=(X\cdot P_{N(A)})v = (X\cdot P_{N(A)})v_1 + (X\cdot P_{N(A)})v_2 = Xv_1,$$
so $v_1\in N(X)\cap N(A)$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much!